# Interrupt ThreadPoolExecutor current threads and empty its queue

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am currently working on an application that has in its main layout a `ListView`, its items are wrappers for real files contained in a directory. 
When the list is populated I execute an AsyncTask that should retrieve some data from a `Properties` file and, if such data is not retrieved, I add a `Runnable` to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to get that data from a website, save it into the `Properties` and then load the `Properties`.

If I decide to change the directory, a `List.clear()` is performed before the app populates it with the new items.

As a consequence, if there are currently working/pending `Thread`s inside the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, they continue being executed and make my application crash, because the item inside the `List` doesn't exist anymore.

I've read some questions but none of them satisfied me. How can I prevent currently active `Thread`s from accessing the List and empty the queue of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Alternatively, how can I design a runnable in such way that if it's not needed anymore it doesn't interfere with the `List`?

**Update:**
In my method to repopulate the `List` I did the following before doing `clear()`:

```
if(mBlockingQueue.size()>0){
    mBlockingQueue.drainTo(new ArrayList<Runnable>()); //I don't want to keep the workers
    mThreadPoolExecutor.shutDownNow(); //This will execute .interrupt(); on the working Threads
}
```

**Update2:**
This is not enough: After creating your executor use the following

```
myThreadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r,ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        //Do nothing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to have a paused tasks list:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = threadPool.getQueue();
List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
int tasks = queue.drainTo(list);
```

Then you can follow this documentation and find a way to use remove on the BlockingQueue

[BlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)